# Lags when rendering multiple ellipses with Cesium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cesiumjs

I'm using React JS with Resium to visualize satellite objects as Entities. They move over time, so their positions are set using SampledPositionProperty. I want to draw a circle underneath them (on Earth). The problem is when I draw 200 satellites with ellipses, fps drops to 2 fps. How can I optimize rendering the ellipses?

```
<Entity position={trajectory.getPosition /*Cesium.SampledPositionProperty*/} point={{ pixelSize: 10 }} >
    <EllipseGraphics semiMinorAxis={1000000} semiMajorAxis={1000000} height={0} />
</Entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing `numberOfVerticalLines` to a smaller value? It should really improve your app's performance

Something like:

```
<Entity position={trajectory.getPosition /*Cesium.SampledPositionProperty*/} point={{ pixelSize: 10 }} >
    <EllipseGraphics semiMinorAxis={1000000} semiMajorAxis={1000000} height={0} numberOfVerticalLines = {10}/>
</Entity>
```